# How to set up a method in wordpress to force user to spent a certain amount of time in a page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My client needs to prove that someone spent a certain amount of time on a page of their WordPress site. Do you know of a way that we could have a page that would have a timer on it that they couldn't click on the next button until the timer hit the right number of minutes? Can any one suggest any plugins or methods to achieve it.

Comment: How reliable should the prove be? The problem is, pretty much everything you do on the client side can be spoofed.

Comment: Actually I need it dynamically added it to every page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pure client side solution I would suggest a javascript plugin that

1. Disables all buttons on page load
2. Sets a timeout
3. Enable all buttons on timeout

In JQuery it would look something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type=button],button').attr('disabled','disabled');
   setTimeout(function () { $('input[type=button],button').removeAttr('disabled'); }, 5000);
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xTnKm/1/)

**Note:** Users with javascript disabled won't have this functionality

Comment: What would prevent me from using the browser console to remove the `disabled` attribute?

Comment: you're right, it totally depends on how save you want it to be, but the script does exactly what he/she is asking for: "have a timer on it that they couldn't click on the next button until the timer hit the right number of minutes"

Comment: Thanks Mark, ButI need it to be dynamically added to every page & admin need an option to setup time manually.

Comment: Then I would write a plugin for it. Add the js to every page with wp_register_script and create an administration part where the admin can set the time. I don't think there's a standard solution for your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Logging page visit times can be done with [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), it's free!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all